# How do I wrap text in a Table cell?

Tags: tabular, tex

I would like to wrap a text in a table. I've tried the following but the text exceeds both table width and page.

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table} 
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
 \multicolumn{3}{l}{Table 1: Dataset, Sources and Construction}         \\ \hline \hline                                          
 No & Abbrev. & Construction                                                 \\ \hline

1 & EquityM & Logarithmic returns of 6 equity markets (FTSE100, NIKKEI225, SPI, DAX30, SPTSX, AllOrds for UK, Japan, Switzerland, Eurozone, Canada, Australia, respectively) \\


 \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Is it a one off entry, or do you want the same formatting for each entry in a given column? In the first case you can use a `\parbox`, in the second a `p` column type.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{6cm}| }

 \hline
 No     & Abbrev. &Construction\\
 \hline
 1       & EquityM & Logarithmic returns of 6 equity markets (FTSE100, NIKKEI225, SPI, DAX30, SPTSX, AllOrds for UK, Japan, Switzerland, Eurozone, Canada, Australia, respectively) \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{Dataset, Sources and Construction}
\label{fig:result}
\end{figure}
```